# Cross section for closed Lie subgroup in a Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ a closed Lie subgroup. Is there an explicit way to construct a local cross section of $H$ in $G$ so that $\pi: G\to G/H$ is a fiber bundle?

Comment: Do you have any follow-up work on constructing the local cross section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider your problem in a generalized setting. Let $H$ be a Lie group and $X$ an $H$-manifold on which $H$ acts freely and properly. There is a unique manifold structure on $X/H$ for which $X\rightarrow X/H$ is a principal $H$-bundle (and in particular, a fiber bundle). If $H$ is a closed subgroup of a Lie group $G$, then $H$ acts freely and properly on $G$ by left-multiplication. You then obtain the desired result.

I have never before attempted to construct explicit local cross-sections. You might try to use the exponential map $\exp:\frak{g}\rightarrow $G$ $ (a local diffeomorphism) together with your surjection $\frak{g}\rightarrow\frak{g}/\frak{h}$ to construct a local section at the identity. Otherwise, I think you might need to consider the Implicit Function Theorem (not particularly explicit).

Answer (score 3):

See page 65 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf).

Comment: Nice book. You should have sent me the link when you answered my question on math.SE :-)